# VBA: Boolean Is not functioning properly

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have an issue with a Boolean in one of my functions. It is called like this

`TxtFile True, FileDir, 1, "Hello"`

and the function is

`TxtFile(WritetoFile As Boolean, FileDir As String, line As Variant, What As String)`.

The first thing the function does is test for a true or false with a simple `If` and `elseif` statment. When I run my function Watch is telling me that `WritetoFile As Boolean` is `false`. But if I call the same function and I step thru it with DeBug, watch says it is `True`. I call the function 8 different ways on another form with no issues.

Edit: Whole Function

```
Option Compare Database
Public ReadOptionsOutput As String
Public FSO As New FileSystemObject
Public TxtFileOutPut As String

Public Function TxtFile(WritetoFile As Boolean, FileDir As String, line As Variant, What As String)
Dim FileContent() As Variant
Dim Idx As Integer
Dim Txtstream As Object

If WritetoFile = True Then
Set Txtstream = FSO.OpenTextFile(FileDir, ForReading, False)
Idx = 0

On Error GoTo Err1 'To catch the last blank line. Dont see another way to see if .ReadLine is blank
Do 'Build an array to edit lines in Text file
    Idx = Idx + 1
    ReDim Preserve FileContent(1 To Idx)
    FileContent(Idx) = Txtstream.ReadLine
Loop
Err1:
Open FileDir For Output As #1: Close #1 'Delet all text inside of File
Set Txtstream = Nothing
Set Txtstream = FSO.OpenTextFile(FileDir, ForAppending, False)
FileContent(line) = What 'Edit line in the array
    For Idx = 1 To Idx - 1
        Txtstream.WriteLine (FileContent(Idx)) 'Write everything back to textfile
    Next


ElseIf WritetoFile = False Then 'Reads Line in file only
Set Txtstream = FSO.OpenTextFile(FileDir, ForReading, False)
NextLine = 1

Do 'Loop thru to selected line and read it
    TxtLine = Txtstream.ReadLine
    If NextLine = line Then
        TxtFileOutPut = TxtLine
    End If
    NextLine = NextLine + 1
Loop Until NextLine > line
End If
Txtstream.Close
End Function
```

Comment: Could you provide the entire code?Which Application (Excel, Access)?

Comment: @Wernerson Edit post with Whole Function and VBA Access tag. Let me know if you want to see others.

Comment: What exactly do you mean with "When I run my function Watch is telling me that WritetoFile As Boolean is false". When I look at the watch (View -> Watch) it's telling me that WritetoFile ist True...

Comment: @Wernerson For example `TxtFile True, FileDir, 1, "Hello"`, with out running with debug, will take that `True` and make it a `False`. Now if I run the same line but this time I use the DeBug to step thru the process. That `True` will stay `True`.

Answer (score 0):

Try and assign a variable in the Sub that calls the function. Like this:

```
Dim WritetoFile As Boolean
WritetoFile = True
TxtFile WritetoFile, FileDir, 1, "Hello"
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Just tried it and it calls it false. Step thru it and it calls it true. Nice try tho. Thanks for your input.

Comment: Maybe a compiling problem ? Try compiling it and running it again.. @Quint

Comment: Just decompiled and compiled it agian. Issue is persistent

Comment: Ok, then you have another option, i don't know what's hapening with that boolean but you can do it with an integer .. "0= false, 1= True" maybe that wai it doesn't get mixed up

Comment: Okay Dim `TxtFile(WritetoFile as Integer,...` and Its taking the 1 in `TxtFile 1, FileDir, 1, "Hello"` and turning it into a 0.

Comment: Whaaat?? that's very weird, do it with a string just for kicks "Yes" , "No" if it turns a yes into a no im turning to religion.. xD

Comment: Well It makes it a `""` now.

Comment: @Quint if i were you i would re-write that code it's very weird what's happening xD